# "CTRL+Comma" search not working in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio-2019

When I try to find anything using CTRL+Comma in Visual Studio 2019, it doesn't show me any results (it doesn't indicate loading either).

However if I have a file called "FooBarController.cs" and I enter "FooBarController.cs" and hit enter, it will open the file, so clearly it still works in some way even if it doesn't show me any results. It is almost as if the search-results are invisible.

I have updated VS2019 to the latest version. I haven't tried repairing yet, and would like to save it as a last resort because I'm worried I might lose important settings.

Comment: Do you already have a solution to this problem? I run into the same problems..

Comment: @Pim Well I switched jobs so I got an entirely new work-PC and VS installation. That seemed to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to my colleague, in his case, the DropdownList part of the ComboBox was resized to minimum.
So just drag the lowest part of the ComboBox where you enter text, downwards, to make it bigger and show the list of items found.